# Change coupon.invalid.code.provided text as GlobalMessage

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm trying to display the custom message, `Invalid voucher code.` when applying an invalid voucher code.

I see the GlobalMessage `voucher.applyVoucherSuccess` defined in `cart-voucher.effect.ts`
and its actual text in the `translations/en/cart.ts` file

But how can I edit the error message when there's an invalid voucher code input?
Or if there's an easier way of doing it in spartacus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there's no easy way or best to do in Spartacus until further notice. However, we do have a way to change the error message for invalid voucher code.

For example, look at the `bad-request.handler.ts`.
You can catch the specific error, which is `VoucherOperationError`. Using this `error.type` from the error response of `{message: "coupon.invalid.code.provided", type: "VoucherOperationError"}`, you can point to the translations `key` or your custom message using the `raw property`.